# Robocup,param was not declared in this scope

Tags: robocup

i want to install robocup rcssserver 15.2.2
after configuration when i press make i get tons of errors saying the same thing: param was not declared in this scope and note: in expansion of macro Builder. what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

You should remove bison3 and install bison2.7 .
For installing bison2.7 read this post.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/444982/install-bison-2-7-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential libboost-all-dev qt4-dev-tools libaudio-dev libgtk-3-dev libxt-dev

$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gnurubuntu/rubuntu

$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo apt-get install rcssserver rcssmonitor
```

Use these commands to install rcssserver & monitor without thinking about dependences